# C# - Как запустить процесс?

Tags: c#

Программа запускает другую программу.

Если запускать как

```
Process pc = new Process();
...
pc.Start();
```

то программа запустится не из своей папки, а из папки где расположена программа проекта.

пробовал так

```
Process pc = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo prs = new ProcessStartInfo();
prs.FileName = runstr;
prs.Arguments = l_args;
pc.StartInfo = prs;

ThreadStart ths = new ThreadStart(()=> pc.Start());
Thread th = new Thread(ths);
th.Start();
```

такой же результат.
Программа запускается, но не видит свои файлы.

Comment: [`WorkingDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) пробовали?

Comment: А вообще-то, процессу должно быть пофиг, откуда его запустили. Если это не так — в нём баг. (Хотя если у вас нет исходников процесса, всё сложнее, самому баг не пофиксить.)

Comment: Эээ... А зачем запускать процесс из другого потока? Что это может поменять?

Comment: Заработало! Спасибо. Просто даже через другой поток пробовал. А тут всего лишь информацию нужно изменить.

Comment: Тогда оформлю как ответ для будущих читателей.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать свойство [`ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(runstr);
var prs = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    FileName = fullPath,
    Arguments = l_args,
    WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath)
};
var process = Process.Start(prs);
```

Обратите внимание, что в `ProcessStartInfo` не устанавливается `UseShellxecute` (в присутствии этого флага `WorkingDirectory` ведёт себя по-другому).